# Windows Firewall stopping sending mail via SMTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

With Windows Firewall enabled (turned on) on Windows Server 2008 my 3rd party application (3ware RAID controller interface) can't send email notifications -
Basically, in the settings, i configure SMTP server, user, password etc...

When i turn off windows firewall, it can send it fine...

Which setting in Windows Firewall would be preventing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added port 25 to the exceptions list and all seems good.

Comment: Using port 25 is bad practice since its the default

Answer (score 1):

Add each application to the firewall's allowed list.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced issues with SMTP outbound traffic and found that it was caused by the virus scanner killing the connections, :|